# How to run a script on system init with root perms in docker debian container?

Tags: docker, shell, debian

How to run a script on system init with root perms in docker debian container and start container like unprivileged user?

dockerlife:

```
FROM debian

RUN apt -y update && apt-get -y install sudo iproute2 build-essential libssl-dev liblzo2-dev libpam0g-dev curl \
    && adduser -q --disabled-password openvpn && usermod -aG openvpn openvpn  \
    && echo "openvpn ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ip" >> /etc/sudoers && echo "Defaults:openvpn !requiretty" >> /etc/sudoers \
    && mkdir /usr/local/lib/gssntlmssp && mkdir -p /usr/etc/gss/mech.d
COPY unpriv-ip /usr/local/sbin/unpriv-ip
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/sbin/unpriv-ip
COPY entrypoint.sh /

COPY openvpn-2.5.3.tar.gz /opt
WORKDIR /opt
RUN tar xfz openvpn-2.5.3.tar.gz
WORKDIR /opt/openvpn-2.5.3
RUN ./configure --enable-iproute2 && make && make install
COPY client.ovpn /etc/openvpn/client.ovpn

COPY openvpn.sh /etc/init.d/openvpn
RUN chmod 755 /etc/init.d/openvpn

COPY openvpn-startup /etc/openvpn/openvpn-startup.conf
COPY service /etc/init.d/openvpn-su
RUN  ls -la /etc/init.d/ &&   service openvpn condrestart  && update-rc.d openvpn-su start 3 && service --status-all 
RUN touch /etc/rc.local && chmod +x /etc/rc.local && echo "#!/bin/sh" >> /etc/rc.local \
    && echo "openvpn --rmtun --dev tun0" >> /etc/rc.local \
    && echo "openvpn --mktun --dev tun0 --dev-type tun --user openvpn --group openvpn" >> /etc/rc.local \
    && echo "pizdec;`date`" >> /home/openvpn/text
USER openvpn
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```

I'm trying to run openvpn by unprivileged user but I need to run `openvpn --mktun --dev tun0 --dev-type tun --user openvpn --group openvpn` as root.

Content of /usr/local/sbin/unpriv-ip

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo /sbin/ip $*
```

Comment: Please, post your dockerfile.

Comment: @AntonioPetricca added. It's ugly for now but please take a look.

Comment: If it has an init system, network devices, and it's manually managing its own network configuration, it sounds a lot more like a virtual machine than a Docker container.  Would running a standard Linux distribution in a VM, and setting up its init system normally, be a better match for your use case?